What is the halachic definition of a mashehu?
In Shabbos 8a, Rashi says that an upside down object thrown into reshus harabim will encounter lavud within 3 tefachim of the ground and that is the moment one is chayav hotzaah. Due to this, if one throws an object that is שבעה ומשהו one is chayav because the object descends into reshus harabim; but if one throws an object of שבעה ושני משהויין, he's patur because it never descends completely into reshus harabim but rather remains partially in the makom petur. The calculation for that is 2.9 (of equivalent mashehuin) tefachim of lavud, and 7.2 tefachim of object equals >10 tefachim, which means the object never completely descends into reshus harabim.
But without a specific definition of a mashehu, I can say that there is always a smaller amount of object that is sticking into makom petur. For example, if the object is within 2.91 literal tefachim of the ground, I can say that an object that is 7.1 literal tefachim is sticking 0.01 tefachim into the makom petur and also in contact with the ground because of lavud. I can also say that when an when an object is 7.01 tefachim, it is in contact with the ground and yet still in a makom petur when it reaches 2.991 tefachim of the ground.
So what is the concept of shnei mashehuin? Without a strict definition of a mashehu, it seems conceptually impossible that one would ever be chayav when an object is more 7 tefachim tall no matter the amount.

The rambam, in his peirush to kil'aim (6,6) says:

ועוד: כל שהוא בארו בגמרא שיעור זה הנוסף שהוא חלק מששים חלק באמה והוא עשירית הטפח
And an additional: "kol shehu". In the gemara they explained that this added amount is 1/60 of an Amma, which is 1/10 of a tefach.

I'm assuming that a "mashehu" and a "kol shehu" are the same thing. Unfortunately, I don't know which gemara the rambam is referencing.

Is he saying that a kol shehu is always this amount or it's that amount In that circumstance?

@DoubleAA I was taught that it's always that amount, but it's not clear from the rambam

@Loani See Bava Basra 53a in the context of performing a kinyan chazaka on karka' by improving the property ("כמה כל שהוא כדשמואל דאמר שמואל גדר גדר והשלימו לעשרה טפחים פרץ פרצה כדי שיכנס ויצא בה הרי זו חזקה").

See the ריטב"א חדשים who explains Rashi with the words, "לחומרא דק, לכולא לא דק".
This means to say that Rashi, when differentiating between 1 משהו and 2 משהויים, is only coming to say that the gemara's measurement of שבע ומחצה is inexact. The distinction the gemara means to make between 7 and a משהו vs 7 ומחצה, is between something that is arguably still within 10 טפחים of the ground,  and something that is clearly above 10 טפחים of the ground.
i.e. Rashi's reference to 2 משהויים is not 2 units of משהו, rather anything beyond the area that could still lead to doubt. This is likely to be significantly less than an absolute minimum value of 7.5 טפחים that the gemara gives.

As an aside, this gemara seems to be fodder for those who are of the position that a legal effect in halacha (a "חלות", in the vernacular) takes some period of time to occur, and is not instantaneous. (A sort of halachic Planck time, if you will...)
